# Codeigniter Tank_Auth used as a HMVC module along with the Template library

Tags: templates, codeigniter, authentication, hmvc, tankauth

I've successfully configured and run HMVC on my clean install of Codeigniter 2.1.0
Then I've included Template library. It consist of only 3 files: /system/library/Template.php, /application/config/template.php and finally, template file itself (somewhere in /views directory).

I've tested template library while loading one of my created modules. I had to go to /system/library/Template.php to correct paths so they point to my module/views instead of default CI's ones.
Then I tested and it seemed just fine.

The third step is to include Tank_Auth authentication library. I want it to reside in module as well (/modules/auth). This module should have the same directory structure just like a regular app directory does (config, controllers, language, libraries, models, views, etc.) so I can copy Tank_Auth's files to Auth module's respective directories.

Basically, I have already done that copy part. But now when I try to run http://adresar.local/auth/auth/login I get

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: auth/login.php
```

I've also tried changing

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller
```

to

```
class Auth extends MX_Controller
```

but to no avail.

If anyone can throw in some useful advice I will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Did you eventually get it fixed? I am having the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, no
I'm still waiting for the solution and it would come in handy because I'm about to start a fresh project and would like to use HMVC along with Template library and Tank_Auth